# Trouble transforming esm files in jest with ts-jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, nrwl-nx, es6-modules

So I have been banging my head on how to get these jest code transforms to work and I have made a bit of progress with transforming the `spin.js` esm files. With that error gone I moved on to the next one which was `angular-instantsearch` but specifically `angular-instantsearch/node\_modules/instantsearch.js`. Here is the error I am reciving:

```sh
.../node_modules/angular-instantsearch/node_modules/instantsearch.js/es/index.js:2
import algoliasearchHelper from 'algoliasearch-helper';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Here is my base jest config that deals with the transforms:

```js
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset');
module.exports = {
  ...nxPreset,
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  resolver: '@nrwl/jest/plugins/resolver',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(spin\\.js|instantsearch\\.js/es)/)',
  ],
  // this caused issues with detecting modules from component files in angular
  /* moduleNameMapper: {
    "instantsearch\\.js/es$": "instantsearch.js/cjs",
    "instantsearch\\.js/es/(.*)$": "instantsearch.js/cjs/$1",
  } */
};
```

Any help on this will be extremely appreciated, thanks!